Linear Progress Iindicator Flutter
In flutter, is possibile to achive a google like style for Linear Progress Indicator, like te picture attached?
This is my code
LinearProgressIndicator(
  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(4), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(4)),
  value: percentage,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  color: Colors.black,
),

where percentage is calculated based on the screen height.
The space between the main line (left) and the ramaining (right); and the stop indicator.


Can't see any attached picture.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GoogleStyleProgressIndicator extends StatelessWidget {
  final double percentage;

  GoogleStyleProgressIndicator({required this.percentage});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 10,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.grey[300],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
            ),
          ),
          FractionallySizedBox(
            widthFactor: percentage,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(4),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(4),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

In this example:
The Container provides the background and border radius.
The Stack allows layering the background and the progress bar.
The FractionallySizedBox adjusts the width of the progress bar based on the percentage.
You can adjust the height, colors, and borderRadius to match the exact style you want. This approach gives you more flexibility to customize the progress indicator’s appearance.
I hope this may help you.
